# Why double line breaks \n\n doesnt work in attachment mail?

Tags: php, email, utf-8, newline, attachment

Im having problems with line breaks when sending mail with php. The main issue here is, that the line breaks doesnt work in mails with attachment (multipart/mixed) but in plain text they do.

```
<?php
function sendMail($email, $name, $pdfpath) {
        // $file should include path and filename
        $filename = basename($pdfpath);
        $file_size = filesize($pdfpath);
        $content = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($pdfpath))); 
        $uid = md5(uniqid(time()));
        $subject = "New attachment mail: ".$name;
        $subject = "=?UTF-8?B?".base64_encode($subject)."?=";
        $body = "Hello Dude!\n\n"
             ."Testing\n\n"
             ."Testing\n\n\n\n"
             ."Testing\r\n"
             ."Testing\n";
        //combine two headers (attachment mails needs to have specific headers)
        $header .= $this->attachment_headers;
        $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";
        $header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
        $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n\r\n";
        $header .= $body."\r\n\r\n";
        $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"\r\n"; // use different content types here
        $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"\r\n\r\n";
        $header .= $content."\r\n\r\n";
        $header .= "--".$uid."--"; 

        //( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )
        return mail($email, $subject, "", $header);
    }
?>
```

So, the output with this in my email is following:

```
Hello Dude!
Testing
Testing
Testing
Testing
```

So, it does add a new line, but only one, I need to have more. How can I do that?

Comment: Are you sure the email is getting sent that way, and that it's not just the email client compacting those lines?

Comment: @Matchu, How could I test that? The source of received mail refers that it is sent with just one line breaks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, I can't find any help from web so I came up with a bubblegum solution. Seems like that for some reason multipart/mixed message strips/removes all additional lines.

```
 $body = "Hello Dude!\n \n"
             ."Testing\n \n"
             ."Testing\n\ n\ \n \n"
             ."Testing\r \n"
             ."Testing\n";
```

See the space between the line break, and the outcome is as it's supposed to.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `\r\n\r\n` instead of `\n\n`.

Answer (score 0):

I know that art2 answer is marked as correct, but I would use nl2br in this line:

$header .= nl2br($body)."\r\n\r\n";

Just trying to help...